# Why does my React app works fine when i downgrade node_modules but fails when update it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, deployment, netlify

I have this app with updated `node_modules` where Signup fails but everything else works. i have a backup of old version of `node_modules` when i replace the current version with that one. it starts to work. I am also deploying it on `netlify`. So when i run `npm run build` and upload the build folder manually to `netlify` it works, but when i try deploying from github, signup fails again.

I tried replacing the package.json with the old one, then running `npm install` but that doesn't work either.

Code for signup

```
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import PasswordMask from "react-password-mask";
import {
  withFirebase,
  firebase,
  FirebaseContext,
  db
} from "../../../Components/Firebase/firebase";
import * as ROUTES from "../../../Constants/routes";
import { compose } from "recompose";
import PhyxData from "../../../Constants/phyxData.js";
import "./styles.css";

const DemoSignUpPage = () => (
  <div>
    <img
      src="/images/demoOnePage/group.png"
      className="demo-page-one-illustration dp-signup"
    />
    <div
      className="lead-text margin-top-40 demo-signup"
    >
      Thanks for trying Phyxable!
      <br />
      Let's continue the healing process.
    </div>
    <div className="center margin-top-16">
      <div className="inline-block">
        <DemoSignUpForm />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: "",
  email: "",
  passwordOne: "",
  passwordTwo: "",
  error: null
};
class DemoSignUpFormBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE, redirect: false };
  }

  onSubmit = event => {
    console.log("sign up submit called", this.props);
    const { username, email, passwordOne } = this.state;
    this.props.firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
      .then(authUser => {
        console.log("sign up submit called 2");
        return this.props.firebase.user(authUser.uid).update({
          joinDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US"),
          userProfile: {
            lastPhyx: { date: new Date(), level: 1, session: 1 },
            subscription: { paid: false },
            progress: {
              posture: {
                1: { 0: { date: new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US") } }
              }
            },
            name: username,
            email: email,
            score: {
              feelingGood: 1,
              lastDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US"),
              longestStreak: 1,
              streak: 1,
              totalTime: 2
            },
            VAS: {},
            currentPhyx: "posture",
            accountType: "USER",
            notification: {},
            signedIn: false
          }
        });
      })
      .then(authUser => {
        console.log("in on submit sign up");

        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        this.setState({ redirect: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });

    event.preventDefault();
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleTryFirstClick = () => {
    this.setState({ redirect: true });
  };
  render() {
    console.log("demo sign up", this.props);
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      // return <Redirect push to="/home" />;
      window.location.href = "/home";
    }

    const { username, email, passwordOne, passwordTwo, error } = this.state;

    const isInvalid =
      // passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === "" || email === "" || username === "";

    return (
      <form className="margin-top-16">
        <div className="center">
          <div className="inline-block">
            <input
              name="username"
              value={username}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Full Name"
            />
            <div className="height-8" />
            <input
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email Address"
            />
            <div className="height-8" />
            <PasswordMask
              id="password"
              name="passwordOne"
              value={passwordOne}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              inputStyles={{
                padding: "8px",
                fontSize: "16px"
              }}
              inputClassName="PasswordMaskInput"
              buttonStyles={{
                width: "61px"
              }}
            />
            {/* <PasswordMask
              name="passwordTwo"
              value={passwordTwo}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              inputStyles={{
                padding: "8px",
                fontSize: "16px"
              }}
              inputClassName="PasswordMaskInput"
              buttonStyles={{
                width: "61px"
              }}
            /> */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="margin-top-40">
          <button
            onClick={event => {
              this.onSubmit(event);
            }}
            disabled={isInvalid}
            type="submit"
          >
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </div>
        {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const DemoSignUpForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase
)(DemoSignUpFormBase);
export default DemoSignUpPage;

export { DemoSignUpForm };
```

Here is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "finalphyx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/lab": "^3.0.0-alpha.30",
    "disable-scroll": "^0.4.1",
    "firebase": "^6.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "mdbreact": "^4.15.0",
    "netlify": "^2.4.6",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-div-100vh": "^0.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-firebaseui": "^3.1.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-jw-player": "^1.19.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.7.4",
    "react-password-mask": "^3.3.1",
    "react-player": "^1.11.0",
    "react-responsive": "^7.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
    "react-share": "^3.0.0",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.0",
    "react-sweet-progress": "^1.1.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0",
    "video-react": "^0.13.7",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1",
    "window-scroll-manager": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.11.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && echo '/*    /index.html   200' > build/_redirects",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "aws s3 sync build s3://www.phyxable.com"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://jacobmjones@bitbucket.org/jacobmjones/web.git"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "homepage": "/",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem as exactly as you described, then it is obviously not a problem with your code but with your dependencies. Notice that it is also natural that if your code works with certain versions it might not work with others (whether upgraded or downgraded)

The first thing i would try is get the old package json, and run a clear install with it (clear your node cache and completely delete your node_modules folder, after you backed up what you need to do). If it works cool, if not, then one of your dependencies has a change that was meant to be minor but yet was a breaking change (it caused your code to stop working)

Now usually because new versions (even ones that were not meant to have breaking changes) can cause breaking changes, npm creates a file that is called package-lock.json. Unlike the package.json this one contains the exact versions that was used during a certain installation, and installing node modules using this package file, should exactly mirror the state of your dependencies at that time.

If you have that lock file and install with it -using npm ci- then it should work.